# Sql query, sub string issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i have a little question to ask

i have a following data in database column .

isLoggedIn=False&CurrentReferral=http://ufone.testSite.tv/Messaging.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/abc.aspx&kw=&FirstVisitDate=10/10/2011 6:52:38 AM&FirstReferral=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare&ExternalReferrer=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare,http://testSite.tv/Signin.aspx&UserTotalVisits=2&ContactId=819&tenantChannelName=Ufone GSM channel&tenantChannelUrl=http://ufone.testSite.tv/&mcid=&ASP.NET_SessionId=ksntwa55yh3u3s45xn5rysyj&IsVisitTracked=yes

what i need to do is to get just only 'ExternalReferrer' from that, 
like

> ExternalReferrer=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare,http://testSite.tv/Signin.aspx&UserTotalVisits=2&ContactId=819&tenantChannelName=Ufone
>   GSM channel&tenantChannelUrl=http://ufone.testSite.tv/

i tried sub string but unablle to get that

```
declare @myData nvarchar (1000)
set @myData= 'isLoggedIn=False&CurrentReferral=http://ufone.testSite.tv/Messaging.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/abc.aspx&kw=&FirstVisitDate=10/10/2011 6:52:38 AM&FirstReferral=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare&ExternalReferrer=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare,http://testSite.tv/Signin.aspx&UserTotalVisits=2&ContactId=819&tenantChannelName=Ufone GSM channel&tenantChannelUrl=http://ufone.testSite.tv/&mcid=&ASP.NET_SessionId=ksntwa55yh3u3s45xn5rysyj&IsVisitTracked=yes'



SELECT  SUBSTRING(@myData, CHARINDEX ('ExternalReferrer' ,@myData ), CHARINDEX ('mcid' ,@myData )) AS Initial
```

m using sql 2008

Comment: What error do you get - I copied and pasted your code and it worked fine

Comment: It gives no error, but it doesn't return the desired result (see the "what I need to do" part in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `SUBSTRING` is the length of the string to be returned, so you have to subtract the position of `&mcid` from the position of `external`:

```
select 
    substring
    (
        @mydata, 
        charindex('external', @mydata), 
        charindex('&mcid', @mydata) - charindex('external', @mydata)
    )
```

---

*EDIT:*

What data are you running my SQL statement on?
I used the `MyData` declaration from your question.

This piece of code runs on my machine in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and returns exactly the desired output as shown in your question:

```
declare @myData nvarchar (1000)
set @myData= 'isLoggedIn=False&CurrentReferral=http://ufone.testSite.tv/Messaging.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/abc.aspx&kw=&FirstVisitDate=10/10/2011 6:52:38 AM&FirstReferral=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare&ExternalReferrer=http://www.testSite.tv/CustomerCare.aspx?link=CustomerCare,http://testSite.tv/Signin.aspx&UserTotalVisits=2&ContactId=819&tenantChannelName=Ufone GSM channel&tenantChannelUrl=http://ufone.testSite.tv/&mcid=&ASP.NET_SessionId=ksntwa55yh3u3s45xn5rysyj&IsVisitTracked=yes'

select 
    substring
    (
        @mydata, 
        charindex('external', @mydata), 
        charindex('&mcid', @mydata) - charindex('external', @mydata)
    )
```

---

*EDIT 2:*

The second parameter of `SUBSTRING` specifies the start position of the returned characters.
In my first answer, this was the first character of "ExternalReferrer=" because of the `charindex(...)`.

If you want to omit "ExternalReferrer=" from the result, you just have to add the length of this string to the second `SUBSTRING` parameter, so that the returned string begins directly **after** "ExternalReferrer=" :

```
select 
    substring
    (
        @mydata, 
        charindex('external', @mydata) + len('externalreferrer='), 
        charindex('&mcid', @mydata) - charindex('external', @mydata)
    )
```

---

*EDIT 3:*

My mistake.
In my last edit, I moved the start position of the returned characters to the right.
But I didn't change the length of the returned string, so of course the end position moved to the right as well (that's why the `&mcid=` stuff was returned again)
The solution is not only to add the length of "ExternalReferrer=" to the starting position, but to subtract it from the ending position as well:

```
select 
    substring
    (
        @mydata, 
        charindex('external', @mydata) + len('externalreferrer='), 
        charindex('&mcid', @mydata) - charindex('external', @mydata) - len('externalreferrer=')
    )
```

Comment: this is what i got Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: wow, its working but can i omit that External from final result?

Comment: @mahisama: Yes, see my answer (edited again). If my answer was helpful, it would be nice if you accepted it as the correct answer (and upvote it, but you can't do that yet, you need 15 rep. for that).

Comment: am geting this part too in result.. &mcid=&ASP.NET_Se  which i dont want

Comment: this is the last this i need. =(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. See above!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@myData, PATINDEX('%ExternalReferrer%' ,@myData ), PATINDEX('%mcid%' ,@myData ) - PATINDEX('%ExternalReferrer%' ,@myData ) - 1) AS Initial
```

But is very specific for that string, so you need to be careful if you have another 'mcid' string in your url.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that every time `mcid` will come right after `ExternalReferrer` then try running this regular expression in your `asp.net` code:

```
/ExternalReferrer=(.*)&mcid/
```

Matching group `$1` will give you the value that you are looking for.r

Comment: This isn't a valid SQL statement

Comment: Tags mentioned with the question also contain `asp.net`, so answer has code that can be executed in `asp.net`